# refresh the itemrenderer of each item in the List component Flex

Tags: apache-flex, list, refresh, draw

I have the list shown below:

```
<s:List id="list2" width="100%" height="100%" dataProvider="{ recordingsShown }"
                itemRenderer="components.VideoItemRenderer2"
                selectedIndex="0" visible="false">

            <s:layout>

                <s:TileLayout id="tilelayout"
                              useVirtualLayout="true"
                              orientation="columns" 
                              columnAlign="justifyUsingWidth" rowAlign="justifyUsingHeight"
                              requestedColumnCount="3"
                              requestedRowCount="2"
                              paddingBottom="5" paddingLeft="5" paddingRight="5" paddingTop="5"
                              verticalGap="10" horizontalGap="10" />

            </s:layout>

</s:List>
```

which displays in tiles a name, a date and a preview image for each one of the videos contained in the arraycollection recordingsShown given as dataprovider.
The problem is when a new video is added,i save the preview pic in a folder and a node describing it in an xml and i put a new item in the arraycollection with

```
recordingsShown.addItemAt(newRecording,0);
```

it is added on stage but the preview image of the last added video is not shown!
How can i redraw the whole list in order to show it?

Here is my itemRenderer:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:ItemRenderer xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009"
            xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark"
            xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx"
            width="400" height="300" autoDrawBackground="true">

<fx:Metadata>
    [Event(name="playClicked", type="flash.events.Event")]
</fx:Metadata>

<fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
        import flash.filters.GlowFilter;

        import mx.controls.Alert;
        import mx.events.FlexEvent;
        import mx.formatters.DateFormatter;




        protected function img_rollOverHandler(evt:MouseEvent):void {
            Image(evt.currentTarget).filters = [new GlowFilter(0xf7941d)];
            Image(evt.currentTarget).alpha = 0.9;
        }

        protected function img1_rollOutHandler(evt:MouseEvent):void {
            Image(evt.currentTarget).filters = [];
            Image(evt.currentTarget).alpha = 1;
        }

        protected function playClickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
        {

            dispatchEvent(new Event("playClicked",true,true));

        }

    ]]>
</fx:Script>

<fx:Declarations>
    <s:DateTimeFormatter id="dateTimeFormatter"
                      dateTimePattern="DD.MM.YYYY HH.NN.SS"/>
</fx:Declarations>

    <s:states>
        <s:State name="normal" />
        <s:State name="hovered" />
        <s:State name="selected" />
    </s:states>

    <s:Rect width="100%" height="100%" radiusX="5" radiusY="5">
        <s:filters>
            <s:DropShadowFilter alpha="0.32" alpha.hovered="0.5" blurX="5" blurY="5" distance="2" />
        </s:filters>
        <s:fill>
            <s:LinearGradient rotation="90">
                <s:GradientEntry color="0x323232" color.selected="black"/>
                <s:GradientEntry color="#7f7f7f" color.selected="0x333333"/>                
            </s:LinearGradient>
        </s:fill>
        <s:stroke>
            <s:SolidColorStroke color="#ffffff" color.hovered="#f7941d" color.selected="#ed7f09" caps="none" weight="2" joints="miter" miterLimit="4"/>
        </s:stroke>
    </s:Rect>

    <s:Label left="10" top="10"
             fontStyle="italic"
             fontWeight="bold"
             color="#f7941d" 
             text="{dateTimeFormatter.format(data.date)}"/>

    <s:Label left="10" top="25" 
             fontSize="16" 
             fontWeight="bold"
             color="#ffffff"
             text="{data.name}"/>       
    <s:Image id="previewImg" left="10" right="10" bottom="10" top="55" scaleMode="stretch" smooth="true"
             source="http://localhost:5080/thumbs/{data.thumb}" /> 
            <!--   source="assets/img.jpg"/> -->             

    <s:Image source="assets/play.png"
             rollOver="img_rollOverHandler(event);"
             rollOut="img1_rollOutHandler(event);" 
             x="136" y="102"
             click="playClickHandler(event)"
             complete="this.invalidateSize()"/>
</s:ItemRenderer>
```

Comment: Make sure that VideoItemRenderer2's set data function properly updates, this may be an issue with recycled item renderers not updating properly.

Comment: how can i check that?If you gave me any example or indication i would be grateful..

Comment: Make sure that the image, and whatever else displays, is set in the `public function set data(value:Object):void` in the VideoItemRenderer2.

Comment: i edited my post with the itemrenderer i use...

Comment: wait... do you have a recordingsShown.refresh() after you add the item to it?

Comment: Yes i tried calling this but nothing, i think this is when you do some kind of sorting to the collection, i just add a new object at position 0..

Comment: I was thinking how can i put a loading gif in the place of the image that is not rendered until it is ready to be shown? any help?

Answer (score 0):

I have found that there seems to be a problem with data binding and the Spark Image. Try adding this to the root tag:

```
 dataChange="yourImage.validateNow();
```

If that doesn't work, set the whole path in dataChange.

Comment: I put this but nothing...what do you mean "set the whole path in dataChange"? Excuse me but i am new to all this stuff.. Thanks a lot for your help beforehand!

Comment: I was thinking how can i put a loading gif in the place of the image that is not rendered until it is ready to be shown? any help? Will this solve the problem?

Comment: Instead of putting the path in the binding expression in the previewImage tag, do dataChange="previewImage.source=http://localhost:5080/thumbs/{data.thumb}".  The problem is that databinding doesn't work on spark images for whatever reason, so you need to explicitly reset the source from outside the Image tag.

Comment: unfortunately it does not work...I was wondering if the problem is that i save the image to my disk and then i update the collection with the new object and they are rendered again from the list,maybe when it is accessed from the disk it is not still saved??Is this correct or? and maybe there is the need to draw again that specific item or the whole list later?

Comment: This is not the problem because i put a timer in order to give time to save the image but again the renderer does not seem to render the last inserted item's image. I tried putting dataChange in <s:ItemRenderer ..> as you told me but it persists...:S Any idea?